# Kivy Camera free resources issue

Tags: python, android, camera, kivy

I want to use Camera to capture photos and scan barcode in my Android app. I added it in kv:

```
<CameraForm>:
    FloatLayout:
        Camera:
            id: camera
            size_hint: (1, 0.8)
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "top": 0.95}
            canvas.before:
                PushMatrix
                Rotate:
                    angle: -90 if app.isAndroid() else 0
                    origin: self.center
            canvas.after:
                PopMatrix

        MDRaisedButton:
            text: "Capture"
            size_hint: (None, None)
            height: "40dp"
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.2, "top": 0.1}
            on_press: root.capturePhoto()
```

And python code:

```
class CameraForm(Screen):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CameraForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fileName = None
        self.camera = None

    def initCamera(self):
        self.camera = self.ids.camera
        self.camera.resolution = (720, 480)
        self.camera.keep_ratio = True
        self.camera.play = True
        self.camera.allow_stretch = True

    def on_enter(self, *args):
        self.initCamera()

    def capturePhoto(self):
        imgTime = time.strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M%S")
        self.fileName = MDApp.get_running_app().imagePath + "IMG_{}.png".format(imgTime)  # store image file
        self.camera.export_to_png(self.fileName)
        msgBox = MessageBox()
        msgBox.showMsg("Information", "Image has been successfully captured!", "OK", False)
```

The similar code I have for Camera to scan Barcode. The problem is when I try to switch from Camera to Barcode camera then I got the following issues:

```
[ WARN:0] global C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_msmf.cpp (1113) SourceReaderCB::OnReadSample videoio(MSMF): OnReadSample() is called with error status: -1072873821
[ WARN:0] global C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_msmf.cpp (1125) SourceReaderCB::OnReadSample videoio(MSMF): async ReadSample() call is failed with error status: -1072873821
[ WARN:1] global C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_msmf.cpp (1159) CvCapture_MSMF::grabFrame videoio(MSMF): can't grab frame. Error: -1072873821
[ERROR  ] [OpenCV      ] Couldn't get image from Camera
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\camera\camera_opencv.py", line 144, in _update
    self._buffer = frame.imageData
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'imageData'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\camera\camera_opencv.py", line 148, in _update
    self._buffer = frame.reshape(-1)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'reshape'
[ WARN:1] global C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_msmf.cpp (1159) CvCapture_MSMF::grabFrame videoio(MSMF): can't grab frame. Error: -2147483638
[ERROR  ] [OpenCV      ] Couldn't get image from Camera
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\camera\camera_opencv.py", line 144, in _update
    self._buffer = frame.imageData
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'imageData'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\camera\camera_opencv.py", line 148, in _update
    self._buffer = frame.reshape(-1)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'reshape'
```

And the app crashes. So, I think it needs to free the Camera resources.

```
def on_leave(self, *args):
    self.camera.stop()
```

When I try to leave camera screen it reports error:

`AttributeError: 'Camera' object has no attribute 'stop'`

But from the kivy docs: https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.core.camera.html#kivy.core.camera.CameraBase.stop

> stop() Added in 1.0.0 Release the camera

So, why `stop()` is not available for `Camera`? How to free the `Camera` resources? Thank you for the help.

Comment: i had the same problem.
The solution for me in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61980957/kivy-camera-on-multiple-screen/61987939#61987939

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `kivy.core.camera.CameraBase` class has a `stop()` method but the `Camera` widget (in your .kv file) is an instance of the `kivy.uix.camera.Camera` class and it does not have `stop()` method.

If you want to stop the camera, you can use the `play` property of `Camera`. [Camera's doc.](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.camera.html)

Otherwise you can use `self.camera._camera` to directly access the `CoreCamera` instance in `Camera` (but I'm not sure if it is recommended).

I recommend that you look at [Camera sources](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/kivy/uix/camera.py) for a better understanding, especially line [102](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/0fc04ca5ecc1397e6624dd870cc19dcf3575b72e/kivy/uix/camera.py#L102) and the definition of [on_play()](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/0fc04ca5ecc1397e6624dd870cc19dcf3575b72e/kivy/uix/camera.py#L113).

Comment: Hello! I have tried the `play` property of `Camera` but it still crashes. I have detected that it crashes on `self._buffer = frame.reshape(-1)` due to buffer overflow when the second camera object is initialized. The only thing I can do, is to merge those camera features together (Camera + Barcode camera), then no such issue will occur.

Comment: If you could give a Minimal, Reproducible Example, I could test it to see if I find something.

Comment: Hello! You can copy my code twice and change screen class name to other or you can create the two Camera screens and try to switch between them a few times and you will get this issue. Thanks.

Comment: I created two classes `CameraForm` and `BareCode` (in the `.py` and `.kv` files) with exactly the same code, I tried to switch between the `Screen` several times and I had no problem, everything works. I tested the code on Debian 10, I don't know if it can change anything.

Comment: I am developing it on Windows 10. On Android no such issue is present. I merged Camera features, then disabled/enabled the appropriate widgets and it works well. Thank you.

Comment: It says in the documentation that the camera initialization is asynchronous maybe the image is white because the camera hasn't initialized yet.